# unable to compile rgdbslam

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, c++, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I've satisfied all the rgbdslam_freiburg dependencies, but during the rosmake command, I get these errors:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5143875/buildfailures-with-context.txt

They are code error(function ecc..), How can I solve it??

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198375/unable-to-compile-rgdbslam/) by [tuxpeppe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20947/tuxpeppe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The core error here looks like the version of rgbdslam_freiburg that you're trying to use was built against an older version of PCL, when PCL used the ROS message types.

Since then, PCL has moved to its own message types; this is why you see function prototype errors trying to convert PCL headers to ROS headers and ros::Time to uint64_t.

I would start by browsing the repository for a version of rgbdslam_freiburg that has already been ported to ROS Hydro or Indigo, and if you can't find anything, you may have to do the conversion yourself. Since the message types are mostly compatible, the conversion shouldn't be too difficult. See the [Hydro migration guide for PCL](http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration#PCL)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tuxpeppe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20947/tuxpeppe/) on 2014-12-01**:
ok, thanks!!